# Access value of array by its index in Angular ngFor directive

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a requirement to access the value of array item by index in `ngFor` directive angular

Let say I have entityList array. I also have columnNames array which gives me number of td's to generate. So columnNames acts as a table header and entityList has data for it to display in tabular format.

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Admin",
}
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Finance",
}


<tr *ngFor="let entity of entityList">
  <td *ngFor="let column of columnNames;let i = index">
    {{entity[i]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I know I can do it like below , however i want to print the value using index and not by name.

```
<tr *ngFor="let entity of entityList;let i = index">
    {{entity.Id}}
    {{entity.Name}}
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to print all properties of entity?

Comment: `entity[i]` is not an array - its an object 

even if you use `entityList`  instead of `entity`  
even than if `i = 0`  that means `entityList[i]` means the 1st object in the array

`entityList[i].Id` you can do - but doesn't serve any logical purpose to me

Comment: I am aware of that, but what do you expect to access by `entry[i]`? Like you just said, it's an object which has properties not indexes

Comment: I have edited question to be more useful. So basically i want a solution so that i can access entityList's properties by index and not by name. What are the ways to achieve it?

Comment: i created an answer, we can keep working on it to find you a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the properties of entry by an index is impossible since it's not an array but an object. What you can do, to get a similar behaviour is its properties with their keys.

ts

```js
  keys = Object.keys;

  entityList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Admin' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Finance' }
  ];
```

html

```html
<div *ngFor="let entity of entityList;">
    <span>
        {{ entity[keys(entity)[0]] }} // here you can access the keys index
    </span>
</div>
```

Basically the idea is to get the property keys in an array, pick the the first/second one and then access the objects property via this key.